# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\left(n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}-n-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Convergence of the following series as $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\left(n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}-n-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)^{-1}$$

As $n \to +\infty$ we have $a_n\sim \left(n^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(n^{\alpha}-n-1\right)\right)^{-1} = \left(n^{\frac{2\alpha+1}{2}}-n^\frac{3}{2}-n^\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}$

Hence, as $0<\alpha<1$ we have $a_n =\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}}\right)$, as $n \to +\infty$, that converges.

As $\alpha>1$ we have $a_n=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^\frac{2\alpha+1} {2}}\right)$, as $n \to +\infty$, which converges in turn.

Is it right or I got rid of too much informations in the asymptotic expansion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

$$n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}=e^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})\log n}=e^{\alpha\log n+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n^2}\right)}=n^{\alpha}\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n^2}\right)\right)=n^{\alpha}+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n^{2-\alpha}}\right)$$

$$n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}-n-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=n^{\alpha}+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n^{2-\alpha}}\right)-n-1+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

and therefore

- for $\alpha<1$

$$\left[\sqrt{n}\left(n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}-n-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right]^{-1}
\sim-\frac1{n\sqrt n}$$

- for $\alpha=1$

$$\left[\sqrt{n}\left(n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}-n-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right]^{-1}
\sim-\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

- for $\alpha>1$

$$\left[\sqrt{n}\left(n^{\alpha\cos(\frac{1}{n})}-n-\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right]^{-1}
\sim \frac1{n^{\alpha+\frac12}}$$

and the given series converges if and only if $\alpha \neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you gimusi, but $\sqrt{n}$ is in the denominator, I am sorry if my text has been not that clear :)

Comment: @F.inc Opsssss...sorry you were clear, I've made confusion. I fix!

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

Comment: @F.inc You are welcome! Your derivation was fine but to clarify any doubt the best way is to consider the Taylor's expansion including the remainder term befor to take the asymptotic term for a certain range of $\alpha$.